# How to get the matching column name when searching across multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, full-text-search, inner-join

Is there a way to get the matching column name when searching across multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Say I have the following table structure and query:

```
CREATE TABLE document (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    document_content VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE story (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    headline VARCHAR
);

-----

SELECT
    "document".*,
    story.id,
    story.headline
FROM
    "document"
INNER JOIN story_document AS Documents_join ON "document".id = Documents_join.document_id
INNER JOIN story ON  "story".id = Documents_join.story_id
WHERE to_tsvector(document_content) @@ to_tsquery('foo')
OR to_tsvector(headline) @@ to_tsquery('foo');
```

I was thinking of concatenating the value of the two columns, run the full text search, then create a sub query for both columns and re-run the search individually and record the result as a reference, but this would mean executing the search 3x:

```
SELECT
    "document".*,
    story.id AS story_id,
    story.headline
    (SELECT "document".id WHERE to_tsvector(document_content) @@ to_tsquery('foo')) AS "matching_document_id",
    (SELECT story_id WHERE to_tsvector(headline) @@ to_tsquery('foo')) AS "matching_story_id"
FROM
    "document"
INNER JOIN story_document AS Documents_join ON "document".id = Documents_join.document_id
RIGHT JOIN story ON "story".id = Documents_join.story_id
WHERE to_tsvector(document_content || ' ' || headline) @@ to_tsquery('foo');
```

How could I get a reference to the column: document_content or headline, where the keyword "foo" was found in one query?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question.

Comment: Actually by the time the two gets joined, it shouldn't matter, anyways.

Comment: It matters quite a lot.

Comment: You make me curious! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the columns are in different tables the best you can do is translate the `OR` into a `UNION`:

```
SELECT
    "document".*,
    story.id,
    story.headline
FROM
    "document"
INNER JOIN story_document AS Documents_join ON "document".id = Documents_join.document_id
INNER JOIN story ON  "story".id = Documents_join.story_id
WHERE to_tsvector(document_content) @@ to_tsquery('foo')
UNION
SELECT
    "document".*,
    story.id,
    story.headline
FROM
    "document"
INNER JOIN story_document AS Documents_join ON "document".id = Documents_join.document_id
INNER JOIN story ON  "story".id = Documents_join.story_id
WHERE to_tsvector(headline) @@ to_tsquery('foo');
```

Then PostgreSQL doesn't have to build the complete join just to filter out most of the rows. My variant will be fast if the conditions are selective and indexed and you have indexes on the join conditions as well, so that you can get fast nested loop joins.

[Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) is some more about dealing with `OR`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of UNION honestly, will read up on it, however its still not clear which column was the source of the match: `document_content` or `headline`. The thing is, on the client side I have to display a reference to one or the other.

Comment: I've updated my question with my naive approach - maybe it helps understanding what I would like to achieve, it works, but its not optimal at all.

Comment: Trivial: add both `@@` expressions to the result list, then you'll get two boolean expressions that tell you what matches.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eye on all the above, really appreciated!